# Is it possible to create Nginx routing configuration from file?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I tried to look everywhere but I was not able to find any solution. I need to create Nginx routing configuration based on a data in my custom file. File will be updated automatically and look like this.

```
api_key_1: instance_id_1
api_key_2: instance_id_2
```

And in nginx.conf I expect something like this

```
upstream instance_id_1 {
     server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

upstream instance_id_2 {
     server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

map $http_x_instance_id $pool {
     api_key_1 "instance_id_1";
     api_key_2 "instance_id_2";
}
```

Is it possible to create the map {} part dynamically according to content of my config file?

Answer (score 0):

How would I solve this task.

1. Use `include` directive in your nginx config:

   ```
   map $http_x_instance_id $pool {
       include /path/to/instances;
   }
   ```
2. Install [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki).
3. Write a script for watching your file (see some examples [here](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes)). On every file change execute something like this:

   ```
   sed -n 's/\(.*\):[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)/\1 "\2";/p' /path/to/your/custom/file >/path/to/instances
   nginx -reload
   ```